# How to create a checksum of a file in python

Tags: python, checksum

I am trying to create a checksum of a file and save the checksum as a file same.  So.I monitor the the file and if the checksum changes then a do something.

Here is the checksum

For test.txt

```
contents: a
checksum: dd18bf3a8e0a2a3e53e2661c7fb53534
```

I edit the file:

```
contents: aa
checksum: dd18bf3a8e0a2a3e53e2661c7fb53534
```

here is my code:

```
python -c 'import hashlib;print hashlib.md5("test.txt").hexdigest()'
```

Why are the checksums the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try to check [hashlib.md5()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html)

```
import hashlib
[(fname, hashlib.md5(open(fname, 'rb').read()).digest()) for fname in fnamelst]
```

Comment: This will not scale for large files.

Comment: Dont need for large files.  But I used hexdigest() instead and need as close of a one liner I could get.

Comment: md5 is broken and should not be used.

Comment: @NDEthos you're overgeneralizing. Yes, it has weaknesses in a cryptographical context and should not be used there. But in contexts where there's no potential attacker that could try to craft a collision, MD5 is still perfectly fine.

Answer (score 7):

> Why are the checksums teh same?

Because you are computing a hash of the same contents `test.txt`.

Here is a general purpose tool (*a clone of the widely available `md5sum` CLI tool available on many Linux and UNIX platforms*) that scales well with large files.

**md5sum.py:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""Tool to compuete md5 sums of files"""

import sys
from hashlib import md5


def md5sum(filename):
    hash = md5()
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(128 * hash.block_size), b""):
            hash.update(chunk)
    return hash.hexdigest()


def main():
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print "Usage: md5sum <filename>"
        raise SystemExit(1)

    print md5sum(sys.argv[1])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Liberally borrowed from: https://bitbucket.org/prologic/tools/src/tip/md5sum

Answer (score 0):

The core hasher functions in hashlib accept the string contents to be hashed, not filenames to open and read, so as James says, you're hashing the same value `'text.txt'` in both cases.

### Python 3.11+

If you're only targeting Python 3.11+, a new option is available: [`hashlib.file_digest()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html?highlight=hashlib#hashlib.file_digest). It takes a file object and a hash function or the name of a hashlib hash function. The equivalent to what you tried would be like this:

```py
import hashlib
with open('text.txt', 'rb') as file:
    print(hashlib.file_digest(file, 'md5').hexdigest())
```

### Python 2.7-3.10+

While `hashlib.file_digest()` will not be available on all supported Python versions until October 2026, we can still take a look inside to get an idea of how we could make an even better version of `md5sum()`, using `bytearray` and `memoryview` instead of `iter(lambda: f.read())`.

```py
import hashlib

def md5sum(filename, _bufsize=2**18):
    digest = hashlib.md5()
    
    buf = bytearray(_bufsize)
    view = memoryview(buf)
    with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
        while True:
            size = file.readinto(buf)
            if size == 0:
                break  # EOF
            digest.update(view[:size])
    
    return digest.hexdigest()
```